# android: how to access a mobile webserver from internet

Tags: java, android, web, ijetty

I can access i-jetty web app installed in android from pc in the same network. but i would like to accesss it from the internet as well. How can it be possible ? The i-jetty server is running on android device.

Or Any other server that can run on android and can be accessible from internet? The there are some applications on the google play, which does the same but within the same network.

Comment: Any luck for accessing the server within LAN? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is inside a lan over a wifi connection you are behind your internet gateway.
So when you want to access a server application on you mobile device from the internet you have to set up a port forwarding on your router from everywhere on the port of the server to your mobile device with the same port.

Or switch with your mobile device into the umts or lte connection, figure out your ip address and call this with a client for your server app.

There are webpage that shows you your ip adress. Try google for "what is my ip".